# SetResult(int,intent) doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting second activity :

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageBox.class);               
            startActivityForResult(intent,5);
```

And then in second i have:

```
          Intent intent2 = new Intent();             
          setResult(RESULT_OK,intent2);              
          finish();
```

And when it comes again to first activity i have :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 

    {

        if(requestCode==5)
        {
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {

            // Toast...
            }

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The problem is i am not getting Toast so its not working. When i am doing setResult(RESULT_OK) its working correct, so the problem is with setResult(int,intent) but i dont really know what is happening.

if it helps all happening in second and third activity in my program but it doesnt really matter.

Comment: can you give the toast line also as you given in your program?

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Try to put some extras to the `intent2`, like `intent2.putExtra("test", 1);`

Comment: i am puting extras ofc, but doest show them

Comment: Try to put `Log` call or `Toast` at the beginning of the `onActivityResult` to check is it even gets called.

Comment: it not getting called you right

Comment: try to change onActivityResult type from protected to public

Comment: still nothing  onActivityResult cant get even called

Comment: Do you maybe start second activity from `onCreate` in first activity? I had that problem too, if you are doing that, try to move it out of the `onCreate`.

Comment: I have tried your code exactly as you posted and it is working very well. I think the issue is some where else.. I will post my code as answer below

Comment: Bobaa you are correct i am starting second activity from oncreate in first activity

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the Comments, my working code is as follows.
**Activity 1** - **On Button Click**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);               
        startActivityForResult(intent,5);   

    }
});
```

**Activity 1** - **OnActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode==5) {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Activity 2** - **OnBackPressed**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent2 = new Intent();             
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent2);              
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) in the beginning.